# getting the content not to become opaque when I make the background opaque

Tags: jquery, html

I am attempting to have a background image that shows full opacity when app launches, but washes out when content is placed over it.
html:

```
<div class="splash_div" id="splash_div" style="background: url('{{ splash_screen }}')  no-repeat">

          <div id="content">

          </div>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#splash_div").css({ 'opacity': 0.5 });
```

This works great, however, my content is  opaque as well.  I have tried moving my background image inside my content, but it disappears when I place content in to my content div.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pseudo element `after`, the pseudo elements `:after` or `:before` transparency will not affect your `splash_screen` div

**HTML**

```
<div class="splash_div" id="splash_div">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.splash_div::after {
    content: "";
    background: url(http://www.freebiesgallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/splash-screen-04.jpg) no-repeat center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;   
}
.splash_div.alpha::after {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#splash_div").addClass('alpha')
```

> Note that you can't manipulate those pseudo elements `after` and `before` using **jquery** to update the background image.

here's a complete example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1j3en42y/)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate `splash_div` and `content`, making the first absolute or fixed position, with negative z-index (or lower than content). In [Fiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/du7eko9a/1/), also below:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#splash_div {
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: .5;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
#content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash_div" id="splash_div" style="background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg')  no-repeat center / cover"></div>
<div id="content">
     <h3>Testing content</h3>

    <p>Opacity is not a problem</p>
</div>
```